# Cannot change the color of the cell of table when hover

Tags: angular, angular2-meteor, ng2-bootstrap

I am using [angular2-meteor](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor) with [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/). I try to change color when I hover on the cell of table.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <td>header1</td>
        <td>header2</td>
        <td>header3</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Aut</td>
            <td>Ieleniti</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Esse</td>
            <td>Ullam</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



.table-hover > tbody > tr {
  &:hover {
    > td {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    > th {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
  }
  > td:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
  }
}
```

The code runs well in the pure Bootstrap, you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/erkoes1p/3/).

But when I use angular2 and meteor, the CSS code won't work any more.

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue. I loaded bootstrap 3.3.6, and it still worked... https://jsfiddle.net/erkoes1p/5/

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**

Comment: It works fine. May be some styles have overridden yours.

Comment: thanks everyone, i think maybe it is related with ng2-bootstrap, so I updated the question.

Comment: You might need to disable encapsulation `@Component({encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None})` in your components or import the style in each component `styleUrls: ['myStyle.css']`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I found the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, my project is a [angular2-meteor](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor) project. At the same time, I am using [Sass for Meteor](https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss/).

When I use `styles: [...]`, Sass for Meteor won't compile it.

There are two solutions, both work:

1. create another file **XXX.scss**, and change to use `styleUrls: ['XXX.scss']`
2. use CSS instead of SCSS codes in `styles: [...]`.

> P.S. These days I met a lot of weird style problems, now it is all because
>   of this problem.
>
> For example, SCSS supports `//` to comment, but CSS not. So when I
>   write codes in `styles: [...]`, CSS codes before `//` work well, the
>   codes after `//` won't work. And I didn't get any error in
>   browser and my compiler.
>
> Hope this can help people who met similar style problems.